# Why doesn't mouseenter execute every time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slick slider and on hover of the slider I want it to go to the second slide. I've managed to do this with mouseenter and mouseleave, however if you hover on/off the slider quickly the function doesn't work.

I'm presuming this is because it doesn't have enough time to complete each function but I'm not sure how to get around this. Any advice would be appreciated.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lym95owu)

JS:

```
$('.slider').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $(this).slick('slickGoTo', 1);  
});
$('.slider').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $(this).slick('slickGoTo', 0);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function that you provided:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    speed: 1000,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: false,
  });
});
```

I see that you have set the speed very high. If you put speed to 10 etc. than it should work better.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue though it just stops the fade/slide effect.